# pander markdown errors with descr::CrossTables if table has no row or col %

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, crosstab, pander

I am trying to find a way to generate crosstables in rmarkdown that can render  to PDF, HTML and word. So far the only solution that seem to work is to generate the markdown tables with pander. However I am having problems with  crosstables with no row or col percentages. When processing a  descr::CrossTables, pander generates a markdown table with duplicated row names.

This code:

```
x<- c('aaa','bbb','ccc')
y<- c('ddd', 'eee', 'fff')  
t1 <- descr::CrossTable(x = x, y = y,
                        prop.c = FALSE,
                        prop.t = FALSE,
                        prop.r = FALSE,
                        prop.chisq = FALSE, 
                        dnn = c('xlabel', 'ylabel'))  
pander::pander(t1, digits = 1)
```

generates this markdown

```
-------------------------------------------------
 &nbsp;\   ylabel\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\ 
 xlabel      ddd       eee       fff      Total  
--------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
**aaa**\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\         1         0         0         1    
  bbb\                                           
   aaa                                           

**bbb**\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\         0         1         0         1    
  ccc\                                           
   bbb                                           

**ccc**\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\         0         0         1         1    
 Total\                                          
   ccc                                           

  Total       1         1         1         3    
-------------------------------------------------
```

See the repeated row labels bbb\ aaa on each row header.

For reference, if at least one % is requested, then the table is ok

This code:

```
t1 <- descr::CrossTable(x = x, y = y,
                        prop.c = FALSE  ,
                        prop.t = FALSE,
                        prop.chisq = FALSE, 
                        dnn = c('xlabel', 'ylabel'))  
pander::pander(t1, digits = 1)
```

generates this markdown, without errors.

```
-------------------------------------------------
 &nbsp;\   ylabel\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\ 
 xlabel      ddd       eee       fff      Total  
--------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
**aaa**\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\       1\        0\        0\        1\     
 Row(%)    100.0%     0.0%      0.0%      33.3%  

**bbb**\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\       0\        1\        0\        1\     
 Row(%)     0.0%     100.0%     0.0%      33.3%  

**ccc**\  &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\   &nbsp;\  
   N\       0\        0\        1\        1\     
 Row(%)     0.0%      0.0%     100.0%     33.3%  

  Total       1         1         1         3    
-------------------------------------------------
```

And the tables render to:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a bug, and someone just reported on [GH](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/278) -- I suggest following the updates on this there.